# Field.types not working when using dbWriteTable from R DBI package in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc, r-dbi

I'm using the DBI package along with the odbc package to connect to a SQL Server database. I'm trying to write a table with column types specified by the `field.types` argument. For some reason this isn't working, and R chooses its own data types when writing.

A reproducible example:

```
table <- data.frame(
  col1 = 1:2,
  col2 = c("a", "b")
)

con <- dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  dsn   = "dsn",
  UID   = login,
  PWD   = password,
  Port  = 1433
)

dbWriteTable(
  conn = con,
  value = table,
  name = "tableName",
  row.names = FALSE,
  field.types = c(
    col1 = "varchar(50)",
    col2 = "varchar(50)"
  )
)
```

The result: a table called "tableName" with columns

```
[col1] [int] NULL,
[col2] [varchar](255) NULL
```

My questions:

1. How can I correct my example above, so that the column types on the database will be `varchar(50)` for both columns?
2. How can I use the `field.types` argument correctly for other examples?

What I would like to know is, what "types" should I use: do I need "int" or "integer" or "INT" (R is case sensitive so it might matter)? And then, where can I find a list of these data types? I have tried using dbDataType, but using the types this function returns doesn't work either. Or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your example (slighly modified):

```
lybrary(RMySQL)
lybrary(lubridate)

conn=dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='', dbname='DB', host='localhost')

table <- data.frame(
    col1 = 1:2,
    col2 = c("a", "b"),
    col3 = c(now(), now()+seconds(1))
)

dbWriteTable(
  conn = conn,
  name='test_DB',
  value = table,
  row.names = FALSE,
  field.types = c(
      col1 = "varchar(50)",
      col2 = "varchar(50)",
      col3 = 'timestamp'
  )
)
```

and it worked smoothly: [image: declare_data_typed_dbWriteTable]

At least the following data types are accepted (from [DBI documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf)):

- integer
- numeric
- logical for Boolean values (some backends may return an integer)
- NA
- character
- factor (bound as character, with warning)
- Date
- POSIXct timestamps
- POSIXlt timestamps
- lists of raw for blobs (with NULL entries for SQL NULL values)
- objects of type blob::blob

Comment: You're right. I retried this, and now it works. Very strange. I'm not sure what happened here but I'm glad it works now. Thx!

Comment: How could we add the field type for a list of variables instead of going one by one?